# entries in page table and size of entry

Tags: memory, paging, memory-address, virtual-memory, page-tables

Given a 16 - bit logical address space, with a page size of 1KByte (2^10), and a physical memory size of 32KByte (2^15).

What are the number of entries in the page table?
16-10 = 6, 2^6 entries

What size (in Bytes) is a page table entry?
I think the answer is 15 bits? but it's asking for bytes so maybe this is wrong?

Comment: Your question has no correct answer under the parameters you have given. The size size of the page table entry is not derivable from your parameters and neither is the number of page table entries—which are governed by a number of other factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoPages = locations/pagesize = (2^16)/(2^10) = 2^6
so there are 2^6 entries in the page table

NoFrames = physicalMemory/pagesize = (2^15)/(2^10) = 2^5
so there are 2^5 frames
each entry in the page table is 5 bits long
therefore the size of an entry is 2^5 = 32 bytes